# получение случайных чисел в r

Tags: случайные-числа, r

здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в r получить случайные числа в диапазоне например от 0 до 10?

Comment: гляньте [тут](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Numbers/Generating_random_numbers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт о равномерном распределении, то используется функция `sample`.

```
sample(x = 0:10, size = 100, replace = TRUE)
```

`size` -желаемый размер выходного вектора.

Другой вариант с использованием `runif` (менее корректный, т.к. используется округление).

```
round(runif(100, min = 0, max = 10))
```